# Android access activity method inside service

Tags: android, android-activity

How to call an Activity's non-static method from inside a service onStart()?

Comment: check this link.

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463175/how-to-have-android-service-communicate-with-activity

Answer (score 5):

> How to call an Activity's non-static method from inside a service onStart()?

You can't.

However, there are many ways to have a service communicate with a running activity, and I outline some of them here: [How can I update information in an Android Activity from a background Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468874/how-can-i-update-information-in-an-android-activity-from-a-background-service/2469646#2469646)

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I have a question, I need to start activity within a service and get result of that activity. Is this possible? Any workaround?

Comment: @saber: "Is this possible?" -- yes, though I recommend that you have good life insurance, if you will be popping up activities from the background that the user does not appreciate. Your service can call `startActivity()`. Your activity can then call `startService()` to send the results, or call `bindService()` and talk to your service via a binder, or use an event bus implementation (`LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus, Square's Otto) to raise an event that the service picks up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, "though I recommend that you have good life insurance", :D ;) Since I don't have good one, I think have to hook up with `LocalBroadcastManager`.

Answer (score -2):

[This](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-call-activitys-method-from.html)  could help ..

In activity define

```
static MyActivity instance;
```

then set value MyActivity.OnCreate

```
instance = this;
```

In your service

```
MyActivity activity = MyActivity.instance;

        if (activity != null) {
            // we are calling here activity's method

        }
```

Comment: nooo, god. no, god, please, no! no no! Never do that. Never. Never retain a static instance of your `Activity`. Just don't.