# My app stops processing when it's in background for a while

Tags: android

I am trying to start a timer at regular interval (through handler) and and write gps location to file upon expiry. However when my app is in the background for a while it seems that it is getting killed or not writing anymore.

Why? Is there a way to do this?

Thank k you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your app to run in the background, you need a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

Alternatively, if you only need to do small tasks every once in a while, you can use a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Comment: I find service to be a lot of work (given what  I have now)or heavy and  I am trying to avoid it (as much as  I can). Would you using Alaram manager/broadcast receiver to open a file/write GPS location every second be too much?

Comment: For every second, I think I would personally stick to a Service. And, as you where initially using, Android docs recommend to use a Handler in your case. (But you need to use the Handler in a Service not an Activity.)

Comment: Thank you so much. this maybe off topic, but how can I update Activity Textfield values from the service?

Comment: Great answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468874/how-can-i-update-information-in-an-android-activity-from-a-background-service

Answer (score 0):

A Handler is stopped indeed when the process is completely hidden, and nothing else is going on in the process. You could use a Service instead, that is "sticky".

Comment: Thank you , I was hoping there is an alternative solution to service. Check my comment to the other answer below