# How to update activity when activity is in background

Tags: android

For example, i do a login operation in activity B and want to update the ui in activity A. How to do that?

Until now, the method i use is to register a broadcast receiver in activity A and unregister it in `onDestroy`. It works fine, but android always give a warning about leaking broadcast.

Comment: Why not just wait until Activity A is in the foreground before updating its UI?

Comment: look this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468874/how-can-i-update-information-in-an-android-activity-from-a-background-service

Comment: That does not seem to apply here.  That question asks "how to update an activity from a background service".  Your question is about updating an activity when the activity itself is in the background.  In fact there is not even a service in the picture in your case.  So again I ask - why not simply wait until activity A is in the foreground?

Comment: @EJK If i update activity when it's brought to front again, i need to save the state whether the data is changed, right?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  The approach you describe is very uncommon.  Typically activity UIs are only updated upon a lifecycle callback (onCreate, onResume, etc) on the activity itself.  It does not sound like your app is doing anything so sophisticated that would warrant such a radical approach.  Perhaps if you posted your code, we could discuss this further.

Comment: @EJK What i asked it like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887169/android-when-to-register-unregister-broadcast-receivers-created-in-an-activity). But i don't think it's a good solution to put unregister in onDestroy.

Comment: BroadcastReceivers are simply not a good fit for what you are doing.